How to install wordlist.txt on ubuntu for gobuster
I am using ubuntu download from Microsoft Store and I have gobuster but I don't have any idea on how to install wordlist.txt for gobuster someone please help me out

Your question lacks any detail. Please read over the info on this link and edit the question and add the details. https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask
